# Learning the "surface" of a function

Tags: optimization

Given a continuous non-convex function and assuming knowledge of all extremum points, is it possible to learn all initialization points from which performing classic GD lead to global minimum? Pure thought experiment, just intrigued. I have heard from a colleague of neural nets that within each layer perform GD but didn't find any info on that online.